# Use a generator for Keras model.fit_generator

Tags: python-3.x, iterator, keras, generator

I originally tried to use `generator` syntax when writing a custom generator for training a Keras model. So I `yield`ed from `__next__`. However, when I would try to train my mode with `model.fit_generator` I would get an error that my generator was not an iterator. The fix was to change `yield` to `return` which also necessitated rejiggering the logic of `__next__` to track state. It's quite cumbersome compared to letting `yield` do the work for me.

Is there a way I can make this work with `yield`? I will need to write several more iterators that will have to have very clunky logic if I have to use a `return` statement.

Comment: Does this help? http://anandology.com/python-practice-book/iterators.html

Answer (score 26):

I can't help debug your code since you didn't post it, but I abbreviated a custom data generator I wrote for a semantic segmentation project for you to use as a template:

```
def generate_data(directory, batch_size):
    """Replaces Keras' native ImageDataGenerator."""
    i = 0
    file_list = os.listdir(directory)
    while True:
        image_batch = []
        for b in range(batch_size):
            if i == len(file_list):
                i = 0
                random.shuffle(file_list)
            sample = file_list[i]
            i += 1
            image = cv2.resize(cv2.imread(sample[0]), INPUT_SHAPE)
            image_batch.append((image.astype(float) - 128) / 128)

        yield np.array(image_batch)
```

Usage:

```
model.fit_generator(
    generate_data('~/my_data', batch_size),
    steps_per_epoch=len(os.listdir('~/my_data')) // batch_size)
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I was trying to do it by passing an instance of a class with a `yield` statement inside the `__next__` method of the class. Your way points out another route, so I'll give this a try.

Comment: @Jessica Alan When while loop will stop in `while True:`??

Comment: @N.IT I recommend researching Python generators. In a nutshell, use of the `yield` statement causes the function to "pause" until it is called again. The loop ends when `generate_data()` stops being called by whatever method is invoking it (`model.fit_generator()` in the example).

Comment: Where do you specify the labels?

Comment: I created a label_batch the same way I created image_batch, then `yield (np.array(image_batch), np.array(label_batch))`.

Answer (score 21):

I have recently played with the generators for Keras and I finally managed to prepare an example. It uses random data, so trying to teach NN on it makes no sense, but it's a good illustration of using a python generator for Keras.

Generate some data

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
data = np.random.rand(200,2)
expected = np.random.randint(2, size=200).reshape(-1,1)

dataFrame = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['a','b'])
expectedFrame = pd.DataFrame(expected, columns = ['expected'])

dataFrameTrain, dataFrameTest = dataFrame[:100],dataFrame[-100:]
expectedFrameTrain, expectedFrameTest = expectedFrame[:100],expectedFrame[-100:]
```

Generator

```
def generator(X_data, y_data, batch_size):

  samples_per_epoch = X_data.shape[0]
  number_of_batches = samples_per_epoch/batch_size
  counter=0

  while 1:

    X_batch = np.array(X_data[batch_size*counter:batch_size*(counter+1)]).astype('float32')
    y_batch = np.array(y_data[batch_size*counter:batch_size*(counter+1)]).astype('float32')
    counter += 1
    yield X_batch,y_batch

    #restart counter to yeild data in the next epoch as well
    if counter >= number_of_batches:
        counter = 0
```

Keras model

```
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten, Reshape
from keras.layers.convolutional import Convolution1D, Convolution2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.utils import np_utils


model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(12, activation='relu', input_dim=dataFrame.shape[1]))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))


model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adadelta', metrics=['accuracy'])

#Train the model using generator vs using the full batch
batch_size = 8

model.fit_generator(
    generator(dataFrameTrain,expectedFrameTrain,batch_size),
    epochs=3,
    steps_per_epoch = dataFrame.shape[0]/batch_size,
    validation_data = generator(dataFrameTest,expectedFrameTest,batch_size*2),
    validation_steps = dataFrame.shape[0]/batch_size*2
)

#without generator
#model.fit(
#    x = np.array(dataFrame),
#    y = np.array(expected),
#    batch_size = batch_size,
#    epochs = 3
#)
```

Output

```
Epoch 1/3
25/25 [==============================] - 3s - loss: 0.7297 - acc: 0.4750 - 
val_loss: 0.7183 - val_acc: 0.5000
Epoch 2/3
25/25 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.7213 - acc: 0.3750 - 
val_loss: 0.7117 - val_acc: 0.5000
Epoch 3/3
25/25 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.7132 - acc: 0.3750 - 
val_loss: 0.7065 - val_acc: 0.5000
```

Comment: That `model.fit_generator` line was painful to read, please consider adding some carriage return when you write oneliners like this one

Comment: Suppose to be `validation_steps = dataFrameTest.shape[0]/batch_size*2`.
Also, `fit_generator()` is deprecated in TensorFlow (I think since v.2.0) and you should pass generator to `model.fit()` instead

Comment: Get `tensorflow/core/kernels/data/generator_dataset_op.cc:103] Error occurred when finalizing GeneratorDataset iterator: Cancelled: Operation was cancelled` error in Tensorflow 2.1.0.

Answer (score 1):

This is the way I implemented it for **reading files any size**. And it works like a charm.

```
import pandas as pd

hdr=[]
for i in range(num_labels+num_features):
    hdr.append("Col-"+str(i)) # data file do not have header so I need to
                              # provide one for pd.read_csv by chunks to work

def tgen(filename):
    csvfile = open(filename)
    reader = pd.read_csv(csvfile, chunksize=batch_size,names=hdr,header=None)
    while True:
    for chunk in reader:
        W=chunk.values        # labels and features
        Y =W[:,:num_labels]   # labels 
        X =W[:,num_labels:]   # features
        X= X / 255            # any required transformation
        yield X, Y
    csvfile = open(filename)
    reader = pd.read_csv(csvfile, chunksize=batchz,names=hdr,header=None)
```

The  back in the main I have

```
nval=number_of_validation_samples//batchz
ntrain=number_of_training_samples//batchz
ftgen=tgen("training.csv")
fvgen=tgen("validation.csv")

history = model.fit_generator(ftgen,
                steps_per_epoch=ntrain,
                validation_data=fvgen,
                validation_steps=nval,
                epochs=number_of_epochs,
                callbacks=[checkpointer, stopper],
                verbose=2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to upgrade **Vaasha's code** with TensorFlow 2.x to achieve training efficiencies as well as ease of data processing. This is particularly useful for image processing.

Process the data using Generator function as Vaasha had generated in the above example or using **tf.data.dataset API**. The latter approach is very useful when processing any datasets with metadata. For example, MNIST data can be loaded and processed with a few statements.

```
import tensorflow as tf # Ensure that TensorFlow 2.x is used
tf.compat.v1.enable_eager_execution()
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds # Needed if you are using any of the tf datasets such as MNIST, CIFAR10
mnist_train = tfds.load(name="mnist", split="train")
```

Use tfds.load the datasets. Once data is loaded and processed (for example, converting categorical variables, resizing, etc.).

Now upgrading keras model using TensorFlow 2.x

```
 model = tf.keras.Sequential() # Tensorflow 2.0 upgrade
 model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(12, activation='relu', input_dim=dataFrame.shape[1]))
 model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))


 model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
               optimizer='adadelta',
               metrics=['accuracy'])

 #Train the model using generator vs using the full batch
 batch_size = 8

 model.fit_generator(generator(dataFrameTrain,expectedFrameTrain,batch_size),
                epochs=3,
                steps_per_epoch=dataFrame.shape[0]/batch_size,
                validation_data=generator(dataFrameTest,expectedFrameTest,batch_size*2),
                validation_steps=dataFrame.shape[0]/batch_size*2)
```

This will upgrade the model to run in TensorFlow 2.x