# Keras(FIT_GENERATOR)- Error, when checking target: expected activation_1 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (32, 416, 608, 3)

Tags: python, keras, keras-layer

I've been working on a segmentation problem for many days and after finally finding out how to properly read the dataset, I ran into this problem:

> ```
> ValueError: Error when checking target: expected activation_1(Softmax) to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape
> ```
>
> (32, 416, 608, 3)

```
I used the functional API, since I took the FCNN architecture from [here](https://github.com/divamgupta/image-segmentation-keras/blob/master/Models/FCN32.py).
```

It is slightly modified and adapted in accordance with my task(IMAGE_ORDERING = "channels_last"(TensorFlow backend)).
Can anyone please help me?
Massive thanks in advance.
The architecture below is for FCNN, which I try to implement for the purpose of the segmentation. Here is the architecture(after calling model.summary()):

1.
[image]

2.
[image]

3. The specific error is:
   [image]
4. "Importing the dataset" function:
   [image]
5. "Fit_Generator method calling":
   [image]

   ```
    img_input = Input(shape=(input_height,input_width,3))

    #Block 1
    x = Convolution2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block1_conv1', data_format=IMAGE_ORDERING)(img_input) 
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Convolution2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block1_conv2', data_format=IMAGE_ORDERING)(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2), name='block1_pool', data_format=IMAGE_ORDERING)(x)
    f1 = x
    # Block 2
    x = Convolution2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block2_conv1', data_format=IMAGE_ORDERING)(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Convolution2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block2_conv2', data_format=IMAGE_ORDERING)(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2), name='block2_pool', data_format=IMAGE_ORDERING )(x)
    f2 = x

    # Block 3
    x = Convolution2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block3_conv1', data_format=IMAGE_ORDERING)(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Convolution2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block3_conv2', data_format=IMAGE_ORDERING)(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Convolution2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block3_conv3', data_format=IMAGE_ORDERING)(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2), name='block3_pool', data_format=IMAGE_ORDERING )(x)
    f3 = x

    # Block 4
    x = Convolution2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block4_conv1', data_format=IMAGE_ORDERING)(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Convolution2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block4_conv2',data_format=IMAGE_ORDERING)(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Convolution2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block4_conv3',data_format=IMAGE_ORDERING)(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2), name='block4_pool', data_format=IMAGE_ORDERING)(x)
    f4 = x

    # Block 5
    x = Convolution2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block5_conv1', data_format=IMAGE_ORDERING)(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Convolution2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block5_conv2',data_format=IMAGE_ORDERING)(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Convolution2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block5_conv3', data_format=IMAGE_ORDERING)(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2), name='block5_pool', data_format=IMAGE_ORDERING)(x)
    f5 = x

    x = (Convolution2D(4096,(7,7) , activation='relu' , padding='same', data_format=IMAGE_ORDERING))(x)
    x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
    x = (Convolution2D(4096,(1,1) , activation='relu' , padding='same',data_format=IMAGE_ORDERING))(x)
    x = Dropout(0.5)(x)

    #First parameter = number of classes+1 (de la background)
    x = (Convolution2D(20,(1,1) ,kernel_initializer='he_normal' ,data_format=IMAGE_ORDERING))(x)
    x = Convolution2DTranspose(20,kernel_size=(64,64), strides=(32,32),use_bias=False,data_format=IMAGE_ORDERING)(x)
    o_shape = Model(img_input,x).output_shape

    outputHeight = o_shape[1]
    print('Output Height is:', outputHeight)
    outputWidth = o_shape[2]
    print('Output Width is:', outputWidth)
    #https://keras.io/layers/core/#reshape
    x = (Reshape((20,outputHeight*outputWidth)))(x)
    #https://keras.io/layers/core/#permute
    x = (Permute((2, 1)))(x)
    print("Output shape before softmax is", o_shape)
    x = (Activation('softmax'))(x)
    print("Output shape after softmax is", o_shape)
    model = Model(inputs = img_input,outputs = x)
    model.outputWidth = outputWidth
    model.outputHeight = outputHeight
    model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', metrics =['accuracy'])
   ```

Comment: does the error happen in fit or compile?

Comment: The error takes places in the "fit_generator"(I forgot to specify that I used Keras's imageDataGenerator together with fit_generator method).

Comment: that means that your y is not the correct shape. What is the shape of your y?

Comment: The shape of the y's(which are masks here) are specified in the imageDataGenerator_instance.flow_from_directory(I uploaded two more photos to be more precise, at [4] and [5].

Comment: could you just explicitly tell me the shape

Comment: 192x192x3 (Width x Height x Channels)

Comment: your y has to be shape 6, 6, 512, or you can add layers to reshape your model output to 192, 192, 3

Comment: Thank you. I will try to reshape, I cannot see how my y can be of input_shape (6,6,512) though.

Comment: in that case you can reshape your neural network output. i can add an answer showing how, but you have to add source code

Comment: Yes, thank you Primusa for the prompt responses.Here is the code snippet(it doesn't let me add here so please check the post up)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original code in the FCNN architecture example works with an input dimension of [`(416, 608)`](https://github.com/divamgupta/image-segmentation-keras/blob/master/Models/FCN32.py#L19). Whereas in your code, the input dimension is `(192, 192)` (ignoring the channel dimension). Now if you notice carefully, this particular layer

`x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2), name='block5_pool', data_format=IMAGE_ORDERING)(x)`

generates an output of dimension `(6, 6)` (you can verify in your `model.summary()`).

The next *convoltuion layer*

`o = (Convolution2D(4096,(7,7) , activation='relu' , padding='same', data_format=IMAGE_ORDERING))(o)`

uses convolution filters of size `(7, 7)`, but your input has already reduced to a size smaller than that (i.e. `(6, 6)`). Try fixing that first.

Also if you look at the `model.summary()` output, you'll notice that it does not contain the layers defined after the **block5_pool** layer. There is a `transposed convolution` layer in it (which basically upsamples your input). You may want to take a look and try to resolve that as well.

**NOTE**: In all my dimensions, I have ignored the channel dimension.

---

**EDIT**  Detailed Answer below

First of all, this is my `keras.json` file. It uses *Tensorflow* backend, with `image_ordering` set at *channel_last*.

```
{
    "floatx": "float32",
    "epsilon": 1e-07,
    "backend": "tensorflow",
    "image_data_format": "channels_last"
}
```

Next, I copy paste my exact **model** code. Please take special note of the inline comments in the code below.

```
from keras.models import *
from keras.layers import *

IMAGE_ORDERING = 'channels_last' # In consistency with the json file

def getFCN32(nb_classes = 20, input_height = 416, input_width = 608):

    img_input = Input(shape=(input_height,input_width, 3)) # Expected input will have channel in the last dimension

    #Block 1
    x = Convolution2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block1_conv1', data_format=IMAGE_ORDERING)(img_input) 
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Convolution2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block1_conv2', data_format=IMAGE_ORDERING)(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2), name='block1_pool', data_format=IMAGE_ORDERING)(x)
    f1 = x
    # Block 2
    x = Convolution2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block2_conv1', data_format=IMAGE_ORDERING)(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Convolution2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block2_conv2', data_format=IMAGE_ORDERING)(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2), name='block2_pool', data_format=IMAGE_ORDERING )(x)
    f2 = x

    # Block 3
    x = Convolution2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block3_conv1', data_format=IMAGE_ORDERING)(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Convolution2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block3_conv2', data_format=IMAGE_ORDERING)(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Convolution2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block3_conv3', data_format=IMAGE_ORDERING)(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2), name='block3_pool', data_format=IMAGE_ORDERING )(x)
    f3 = x

    # Block 4
    x = Convolution2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block4_conv1', data_format=IMAGE_ORDERING)(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Convolution2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block4_conv2',data_format=IMAGE_ORDERING)(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Convolution2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block4_conv3',data_format=IMAGE_ORDERING)(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2), name='block4_pool', data_format=IMAGE_ORDERING)(x)
    f4 = x

    # Block 5
    x = Convolution2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block5_conv1', data_format=IMAGE_ORDERING)(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Convolution2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block5_conv2',data_format=IMAGE_ORDERING)(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Convolution2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block5_conv3', data_format=IMAGE_ORDERING)(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2), name='block5_pool', data_format=IMAGE_ORDERING)(x)
    f5 = x

    x = (Convolution2D(4096,(7,7) , activation='relu' , padding='same', data_format=IMAGE_ORDERING))(x)
    x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
    x = (Convolution2D(4096,(1,1) , activation='relu' , padding='same',data_format=IMAGE_ORDERING))(x)
    x = Dropout(0.5)(x)

    x = (Convolution2D(20,(1,1) ,kernel_initializer='he_normal' ,data_format=IMAGE_ORDERING))(x)
    x = Convolution2DTranspose(20,kernel_size=(64,64), strides=(32,32),use_bias=False,data_format=IMAGE_ORDERING)(x)
    o_shape = Model(img_input, x).output_shape

    # NOTE: Since this is channel last dimension ordering, the height and width dimensions are along [1] and [2], not [2] and [3]
    outputHeight = o_shape[1]
    outputWidth = o_shape[2]

    x = (Reshape((outputHeight*outputWidth, 20)))(x) # Channel should be along the last dimenion of reshape
    # No need of permute layer anymore

    print("Output shape before softmax is", o_shape)
    x = (Activation('softmax'))(x)
    print("Output shape after softmax is", o_shape)
    model = Model(inputs = img_input,outputs = x)
    model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', metrics =['accuracy'])

    return model

model = getFCN32(20)
print(model.summary())
```

Next I will provide with snippets of how my `model.summary()` looks. If you take a look at the last few layers, it is something like this:
[image: Model summary]

So this means, the `conv2d_transpose` layer produces an output of dimension `(448, 640, 20)` and *flattens* it out before applying *softmax* on it. So dimension of output is `(286720, 20)`. Similarly your `target_generator` (`mask_generator` in your case) should also generate targets of similar dimension. Similarly, your `input_generator` should also be producing input batches of size `[batch size, input_height,input_width, 3]`, as mentioned in the `img_input` of your function.

Hopefully this will help you to get to the bottom of your problem and figure out a suitable solution. Please take a look at the minor variations in the code (along with the in-line comments) and how to create your **input** and **target** batches.

Comment: Apparently the code line o=f5 did not function properly, so yes you were right in that regard.

Comment: I replaced all the functional calls with (x) at every step, but now I get another error

Comment: What is the new error? Also did you take care of your input dimension so that it does not reduce to a size smaller than (7, 7)?

Comment: I believe this is due to the manner in which I import my dataset in the import function. ( flow_from_directory (batch_size =32, etc)

Comment: This line is supposed to resize your output from convolution layer and flatten it: o = (Reshape(( -1  , outputHeight*outputWidth   )))(o)


I see you have both this as well as a flatten layer. Can you please remove the flatten layer and check if you get the expected dimensional output, as given in this link: https://github.com/divamgupta/image-segmentation-keras/blob/master/Models/FCN32.py

Comment: Ok so we're getting close to the good result. I deleted the Flatten layer and changed from (7,7) to (6,6) and now it gives me the error ("Error when checking target: expected activation_4 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (32, 416, 608, 3") ). So I assume it expects to have the shape (416,608,3) instead of (32(presumably batch size), 416,608,3). What now?

Comment: No, it expects your size to be (batch size, height * width, channel). Converting it from (batch size, channel, height, width) to (batch size, channel, height * width) is what the reshape layer does. Finally the permute layer converts it to (batch size, height * width, channel).

Comment: Using "channels_first" instead of "channels_last" does not solve the issue. What do you suggest I should do?

Comment: No. If you notice your error, it says your height and width are still separate. They are not merged. Please go through your errors carefully. There's enough information in it to get it resolved.

Comment: Thank you, but trust me that If I knew how to solve this issue I would not have posted it here in the first place. I understand what Reshape and Permute layers do, yet I do not know what I should write/do in order to solve it now.

Comment: Change channel_last to channel_first and see if that resolves it. But from the error message you posted above, it seems reshape isn't giving the expected output. The height and width are supposed to be merged after that.

Comment: No, it doesn't solve it. I tried it again but just like I stated in the comment above, this doesn't solve the problem. And yes, the height and width are supposed to be merged, hence my frustration :)

Comment: Print the dimension just before the reshape layer and see if there's some little bug in that. I'm not in front of my computer now, else would have debugged it and let you know.

Comment: Output shape before reshape is (None, 448, 640, 20),     
    Output Height is: 448 ,   
    Output Width is: 640  ,  
    Output shape after reshape (?, ?, 286720),      
    Output shape after permute is (?, 286720, ?),      
    Output shape after softmax is (?, 286720, ?).

Comment: So you see, before reshape, shape is (height, width, channel). That is channel last. But in reshape you're asking it to do (channel, height * width). That is, channel first. Hence the source of your error. Did you get it now?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Writing Reshape( outputWidth  * outputHeight , -1) indeed reshaped it correctly, so no need to permute it now. But now it has [batch_size,width*height,channel], and the error is the same.

Comment: I also left the original setting with channel_first and it still gives the same error. My opinion is that with the input shape(what I send there is a problem). But I don't understand why Keras's fit_generator simply would not work, as I took the image_preprocessing step from their documentation.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you Koustav, this is also exactly the output from the model.summary() in my case.  My problem is that I do not know how to create the target batches with this shape in this case, because I use from Keras's documentation specifically for images&masks, which produce an output of dimension 4(for the target shape)(the generator produces such output). This is what I do not know, how to modify in(see image [4]) to correctly fit it in (see image[5]), the import of the dataset in order to fit it correctly to my architecture. If you know how to do that, I would be very grateful.

Comment: Write your own generator function. Some pointers are as follows: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/8078#issuecomment-334909314 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46493419/use-a-generator-for-keras-model-fit-generator.

Because anyway you are outputting a 20-channel image, hence just using native Keras image pre-processing functions may not be a good idea as they only work well for regular (RGB or Grayscale) images. You need to write your own generator function to load the target 20-channeled GT image.

Comment: Massive thanks Koustav. As soon as I manage to do it, I will tell you :D

Comment: Take a look at this. This is a generator for generating segmentation input and GT. This may be useful to you.
https://github.com/divamgupta/image-segmentation-keras/blob/master/LoadBatches.py

Answer (score 0):

I tried using SegNet architecture and yet again and I get the exact same error.
It appears it is not an architectural problem, but one from fit_generator && from using masks.

UPDATE: The problem was solved by feeding the correct form of the input masks to the neural network.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably missing `color_mode='grayscale'` in the `flow_from_directory()` call for the mask.  RGB is the default value for `color_mode`.

```
flow_args = dict(
    batch_size=batch_size,
    target_size=target_size,
    class_mode=None,
    seed=seed)

image_generator = image_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    image_dir, subset='training', **flow_args)

mask_generator = mask_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    mask_dir, subset='training', color_mode='grayscale', **flow_args)
```