# ImageDataGenerator causes unwanted color changes in images

Tags: tensorflow, image-processing, keras, data-augmentation

Finally I have a question for which I didn't find any answer searching stack overflow. :)
I have the issue that the ImageDataGenerator from Keras changes the RGB values of images when it should not.

Right now, I am working on semantic segmentation of images of electric motors. I use the ImageDataGenerator for the augmentation of my training data. The masks contain 7 classes which are saved as RGB values.

Now I face the issue that the ImageDataGenerator changes the RGB values while performing rotation or width/height shift. This affects the quality of the segmentation, since all the pixels which have a RGB value different to the original values are assigned to the wrong class.

Here is my code:

```
#mask is array of shape [256,256,3]
x=mask.reshape((1,)+mask.shape)

#Reshaping the mask array from [256,256,3] to [65536,3]
colors = mask.reshape(-1, mask.shape[-1])  

#Printing all unique values contained in the array
print(np.unique(mask,axis=0, return_counts = True))

>>> (array([[  0.,   0.,   0.],
       [  0.,   0., 255.],
       [  0., 255.,   0.],
       [  0., 255., 255.],
       [255.,   0.,   0.],
       [255.,   0., 255.],
       [255., 255., 255.]], dtype=float32), array([  185,   198,  1839,   164,  6424,   116, 56610], dtype=int64))
                               
           
data_gen_args = dict( 
                   rotation_range=90,
                   width_shift_range=0.2,
                   height_shift_range=0.2,
                   horizontal_flip=True,
                   vertical_flip=True,
                   fill_mode='nearest',
                   dtype='float32'                                  
                                 )
            
image_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(**data_gen_args)           
image_datagen.fit(x, augment=True, seed=seed])            
y=next(image_datagen.flow(x, batch_size=1, seed=seed]))
y=y[0,:,:,:]

#printing all colors of the mask after the augmentation    
colors = y.reshape(-1, y.shape[-1])    
print(np.unique(y,axis=0, return_counts = True))   

>>> (array([[  0.        ,   0.        , 255.        ],
   [  0.       , 0.81301534, 0.81301534],
   [  0.       , 1.3285289 , 0.        ],
   ...,
   [255.       , 254.28366 , 254.28366 ],
   [255.       , 254.6897  , 254.6897  ],
   [255.       , 255.      , 255.      ]], dtype=float32), array([  166,     1,     1, ...,     1,     1, 56319], dtype=int64))
```

This shows there are only 7 different RGB values in the original mask. Doing the same after the augmentation reveals additional RGB values. If I only use horizontal/vertical flip the augmented mask contains only the original RGB values. So my problem seems to be linked to the rotation and width/height shift of the DataGenerator.

Comment: do you resize your images and masks ?

Comment: No, the masks are not resized. I load them using load_img() and convert them to an array with img_to_array(). I already checked the RGB values of the mask arrays with np.unique(). The colors are correct before the masks are passed to the DataGenerator.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [keras ImageDataGenerator interpolates binary mask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60521736/keras-imagedatagenerator-interpolates-binary-mask)

Comment: How do you know it changes the values? Please provide evidence of such changed values. Thank you.

Comment: @AlexK I think the solution doesn't work in my case since I have a mask containing mutiple classes. As far as I am concerned np.where() would not work since the maks array [256,256,3] containes RGB values. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Kepler np.where(batch>128, 255, 0)

Comment: @MarkSetchell See my edited question

Comment: I don't understand. I see 7 colours before and 7 after. I don't know what you did in between, nor why you think the number of colours has changed... can you make it easier to see the problem please? Thank you.

Comment: @MarkSetchell
Sorry this is my first post, so I am not to familiar with the whole process. I edited my question and added more code. I hope it is more clear now.

Comment: @AlexK. what do you mean with batch?

Comment: That was based on original suggestion, in its terms