# Create a mixed data generator (images,csv) in keras

Tags: python, keras

I am building a model with multiple inputs as shown in [pyimagesearch](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2019/02/04/keras-multiple-inputs-and-mixed-data/), however I can't load all images into RAM and I am trying to create a generator that uses `flow_from_directory` and get from a CSV file all the extra attributes for each image being processed.

**Question:** How do I get the attributes from the CSV to correspond with the images in each batch from the image generator?

```
def get_combined_generator(images_dir, csv_dir, split, *args):
    """
    Creates train/val generators on images and csv data.

    Arguments:

    images_dir : string
        Path to a directory with subdirectories for each class.

    csv_dir : string
        Path to a directory containing train/val csv files with extra attributes.

    split : string
        Current split being used (train, val or test)
    """
    img_width, img_height, batch_size = args

    datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        rescale=1. / 255)

    generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
        f'{images_dir}/{split}',
        target_size=(img_width, img_height),
        batch_size=batch_size,
        shuffle=True,
        class_mode='categorical')

    df = pd.read_csv(f'{csv_dir}/{split}.csv', index_col='image')

    def my_generator(image_gen, data):
        while True:
            i = image_gen.batch_index
            batch = image_gen.batch_size
            row = data[i * batch:(i + 1) * batch]
            images, labels = image_gen.next()
            yield [images, row], labels

    csv_generator = my_generator(generator, df)

    return csv_generator
```

Comment: Does the `csv` file contain information that you cannot include in the image file names? If so, then it might be easier to just create a custom generator.

Comment: It does, the csv has attributes relevant to each image, i am working with images of buildings and it has latitude, longitude, number of stories and other attributes like that for each image.

Comment: How do you feed it yo your model? I think it's possible to create such batch with dataset api functionality. Could you give more specifics?

Comment: I am using fit_generator and passing the csv_generator from my code, i create train_gen and val_gen using this code.

Comment: Why not just use a custom generator?

Comment: I am interested in what happens if all data are in single .csv, any solutions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a solution based on Luke's answer using a custom generator

```
import random
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from glob import glob
from keras.preprocessing import image as krs_image

# Create the arguments for image preprocessing
data_gen_args = dict(
    horizontal_flip=True,
    brightness_range=[0.5, 1.5],
    shear_range=10,
    channel_shift_range=50,
    rescale=1. / 255,
)

# Create an empty data generator
datagen = ImageDataGenerator()

# Read the image list and csv
image_file_list = glob(f'{images_dir}/{split}/**/*.JPG', recursive=True)
df = pd.read_csv(f'{csv_dir}/{split}.csv', index_col=csv_data[0])
random.shuffle(image_file_list)

def custom_generator(images_list, dataframe, batch_size):
    i = 0
    while True:
        batch = {'images': [], 'csv': [], 'labels': []}
        for b in range(batch_size):
            if i == len(images_list):
                i = 0
                random.shuffle(images_list)
            # Read image from list and convert to array
            image_path = images_list[i]
            image_name = os.path.basename(image_path).replace('.JPG', '')
            image = krs_image.load_img(image_path, target_size=(img_height, img_width))
            image = datagen.apply_transform(image, data_gen_args)
            image = krs_image.img_to_array(image)

            # Read data from csv using the name of current image
            csv_row = dataframe.loc[image_name, :]
            label = csv_row['class']
            csv_features = csv_row.drop(labels='class')

            batch['images'].append(image)
            batch['csv'].append(csv_features)
            batch['labels'].append(label)

            i += 1

        batch['images'] = np.array(batch['images'])
        batch['csv'] = np.array(batch['csv'])
        # Convert labels to categorical values
        batch['labels'] = np.eye(num_classes)[batch['labels']]

        yield [batch['images'], batch['csv']], batch['labels']
```

Answer (score 6):

I would suggest creating a custom generator given this relatively specific case. Something like the following (modified from a similar answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46493419/use-a-generator-for-keras-model-fit-generator/46497414#46497414)) should suffice:

```
import os
import random
import pandas as pd

def generator(image_dir, csv_dir, batch_size):
    i = 0
    image_file_list = os.listdir(image_dir)
    while True:
        batch_x = {'images': list(), 'other_feats': list()}  # use a dict for multiple inputs
        batch_y = list()
        for b in range(batch_size):
            if i == len(image_file_list):
                i = 0
                random.shuffle(image_file_list)
            sample = image_file_list[i]
            image_file_path = sample[0]
            csv_file_path = os.path.join(csv_dir,
                                         os.path.basename(image_file_path).replace('.png', '.csv'))
            i += 1
            image = preprocess_image(cv2.imread(image_file_path))
            csv_file = pd.read_csv(csv_file_path)
            other_feat = preprocess_feats(csv_file)
            batch_x['images'].append(image)
            batch_x['other_feats'].append(other_feat)
            batch_y.append(csv_file.loc[image_name, :]['class'])

        batch_x['images'] = np.array(batch_x['images'])  # convert each list to array
        batch_x['other_feats'] = np.array(batch_x['other_feats'])
        batch_y = np.eye(num_classes)[batch['labels']]
        yield batch_x, batch_y
```

Then, you can use Keras's [fit_generator()](https://keras.io/models/sequential/#fit_generator) function to train your model.

Obviously, this assumes you have `csv` files with the same names as your image files, and that you have some custom `preprocessing` functions for images and `csv` files.

Comment: Thanks Luke, your answer helped me to solve my problem, however your custom generator doesn't yield (x,y) to be accepted by keras, or in my case ([x1,x2], y)

Comment: Glad you solved your problem. You're right, I should have added that to the generator - this was simply meant as an example of how you would do what you asked. I have added that part of the code in based on your answer. Be sure to accept your answer so others can see it and upvote any that were helpful, by the way.