# Generator function in keras for mixed data input (image, csv) - R

Tags: r, image, tensorflow, keras

I want to build a generator function to input Image Data together with the corresponding metadata. There are more than 20 k Images and that is why I can't just read them into memory. I have tried also to use flow_from_dataframe but in the multi-input case it's getting complicated.

The generator function looks like this:

```
data_files_generator_train <- function(dir) {


  files <- list.files(dir ,pattern = "jpg$")
  next_file <- 0

  function() {

next_file <<- next_file + 1

if (next_file > length(files))
{next_file <<- 1}

# determine the file name
file <- files[[next_file]]

image <- image_load(file, target_size = c(150,150)) %>%
  image_to_array() %>%
  array_reshape(dim = c(150, 150, 3)) %>%
  imagenet_preprocess_input()
x_image <- image/ 255

x_attr <- paintings_attributes_train %>% filter(path == file) %>% select(-c(target, path)) 

y <- paintings_attributes_train %>% filter(path == file) %>% select(target) 

x_attr <- matrix(x_attr, ncol = 16)
y <- matrix(y)

return(list(list(x_image, x_attr), y)) 
}}
```

I get the following error:

> Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : 
>     ValueError: Error when checking model input: the list of Numpy arrays that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected. Expected to see 2 array(s), but instead got the following list of 1 arrays: [array([[0.00769116, 0.17699115, 0.1436

the model definition looks as follows:

```
vision_model <- keras_model_sequential() 

vision_model %>% 
  layer_conv_2d(filters = 64, 
                kernel_size = c(3, 3), 
                activation = 'relu', 
                padding = 'same',
                input_shape = c(150, 150, 3)) %>% 
  layer_max_pooling_2d(pool_size = c(2, 2)) %>% 
  layer_flatten()

# tensor with the output of our vision model:
image_input <- layer_input(shape = c(150, 150, 3))
encoded_image <- image_input %>% vision_model

tabular_input <- layer_input(shape = 16, dtype = 'float32')

mlp_model <- tabular_input %>% 
  layer_dense(
    units              = 16, 
    kernel_initializer = "uniform", 
    activation         = "relu") 

# concatenate the metadata vector and the image vector then
# train a linear regression on it
output <- layer_concatenate(c(mlp_model, encoded_image)) %>% 
  layer_dense(units = 1, activation='linear')


# This is our final model:
vqa_model <- keras_model(inputs = c(tabular_input, image_input), outputs = output)
```

The Question is related to [Create a mixed data generator (images,csv) in keras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55266249/create-a-mixed-data-generator-images-csv-in-keras).

Thanks for any help!

Comment: is it `r` or `python`?