# Tensorflow add feature in image classification

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, medical-imaging

I have a dataset with COVID died/lived X-Ray images and some features. I create the input layer with `ImageDataGenerator.flow_from_directory` after I have parsed a CSV file which includes all file names.

CSV has many other useful columns, except the file name and the output binary result (died/lived) I will train the model to predict, like for example if the image belongs to a male or a female or if the patient has high blood sugar etc.

Since the output is affected from either the patient is male or female (men are most likely to die), I want this column to be used as an input parameter along with the X-Ray, so the model will have better predictions.

I would really appreciate some help here!

Thank you

Comment: https://pyimagesearch.com/2019/02/04/keras-multiple-inputs-and-mixed-data/

Comment: Here you go: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68804308/2423278

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Concatenate Image and CSV data Tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68793010/concatenate-image-and-csv-data-tensorflow)